# Sibling selector doesn't work when selecting sibling of :invalid or :valid

Tags: html, css

After validation, the test-validated class is added to the form, and the invalid descendants are styled with a red border (this is working).

The div with class feedback, which is a sibling to the :invalid input should be styled with display: block; but this is not working.

```css
.test-validated :invalid {
  border-color: red;
}

.feedback {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}

.test-validated :invalid~.feedback {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form class="w3-container test-form" novalidate action="scripts/process_feedback.php" method="post">
  <input class="w3-input" type="text" name="firstName" required pattern="^[A-Z][A-Za-z '-]*$">
  <div class="feedback">
    Please choose a username.
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What Techy said is correct, you're formatting is incorrect, no space between the selector and :invalid.

Comment: Your code seems to works fine. If you add the class `.test-validated` to the form, the `.feedback` div is displayed like in this example : https://jsfiddle.net/0v1qc62w/ . The space before the `:invalid` isn't a typo as is selects descendents of the the `.test-validated` form element.

Comment: How do you validate if the form has `novalidate`? From the input don't type in anything and then hit Enter. Your `required` attribute should've stopped because the input is invalid.